# Shell nested for loop and string comparison

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two files
file1

```
104.128.225.208:8000
103.27.24.114:80
104.128.225.208:8000
```

and file2

```
103.27.24.114:99999999
103.27.24.114:88888888888
104.128.225.208:8000
103.27.24.114:80
104.128.225.208:8000
```

and in file2 there are two new lines

```
103.27.24.114:99999999
103.27.24.114:88888888888
```

So I want to check if there are new lines in file

```
for i in $(cat $2)
    do
        for j in $(cat $1)
        do
            if [ $i = $j ]; then
                echo $i
            fi
        done
    done

/.program file1 file2
```

but I don't get expected output. I think that my if statement is not working fine. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Comment: `comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably that you are looping over *every line* in file1 for *each* line in file2.

The [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/comm) utility does what you want, but it assumes both files are sorted.

```
$ sort file1 -o file1
$ sort file2 -o file2
$ comm -13 file1 file2
103.27.24.114:99999999
103.27.24.114:88888888888
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `diff` is for. Example:

```
$ diff dat/newdat1.txt dat/newdat2.txt
0a1,2
> 103.27.24.114:99999999
> 103.27.24.114:88888888888
```

Where `newdat1.txt` and `newdat2.txt` are:

```
104.128.225.208:8000
103.27.24.114:80
104.128.225.208:8000
```

and

```
103.27.24.114:99999999
103.27.24.114:88888888888
104.128.225.208:8000
103.27.24.114:80
104.128.225.208:8000
```

You can simply test the return of `diff` with or without output depending on the options and your needs. (e.g. `if diff -q $file1 $file2 >/dev/null; then echo same; else echo differ; fi`)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in $(diff file1 file2); do 
   if [ -z "$firstLineDiscarded" ]; then
       firstLineDiscarded=TRUE
   elif [ $n != ">" ]; then 
      echo $n
  fi
done
```

If you're not attached to that particular approach this seems to work.

Of course it breaks down if the input syntax changes (includes spaces in the data), but for this strict application... maybe good enough.